# Need to create a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

```
if(filename==x) 
 exec stored procedure1 

else if (filename==y) 
 exec stored  procedure2 

else 
exec  stored  procedure3

filename is stored in a table .
```

How to do this in sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a part you're having trouble with? This is how you would get the file name from a table:

```
Declare @filename nvarchar(100)
Select @filename = filename_column from tablename
```

The syntax for if statements is

```
If @filename='xxx'
Begin
...
End
```

Executing a stored procedure is done with `exec`, just like in your pseudo code.